# No preview images for dataset in ClearML web UI

Tags: python, clearml

After creating a new dataset via CLI for a bunch of images, I closed that dataset and thus uploaded it to our own, newly installed ClearML server. Now in the web UI the new dataset has been created and can be opened, the images are being listed. However, none of the images within that dataset is shown in any of the previews.

Here is a simple script to test this:

```py
from clearml import Dataset

IMG_PATH = "/home/mfb/Temp/sample-ds/50-ok.jpg"

# Create dataset and add sample image
ds = Dataset.create(dataset_name="Test", dataset_project="Dataset-Test")
ds.add_files(path=IMG_PATH)
ds.upload()

# Add and report image
logger = ds.get_logger()
logger.report_image("image", "sample image", iteration=0, local_path=IMG_PATH)
logger.flush()

# Finalize the dataset
ds.finalize()
```

But there are no sample images in the web UI:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm a member of the ClearML team (formerly Trains)

This issue is already solved in current ClearML SDK versions (v1.9.3 as of today) and was likely related to the ClearML SDK reporting service exiting prematurely on program exit (reported on Windows).